# Grouping data with separate filter (MongoDB query)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Im trying to create a query which will basically GROUP and COUNT male and female gender per day. The mongodb query will be executed in jaspersoft studio using mongodb adapter.

My main problem here is how will the query count how many male and female per day using $group.
I hope someone can help me in this problem. Thank you in advance

```
{
runCommand: {
    aggregate: "visit",
    pipeline: [



{ $lookup: { from: 'person', localField: 'personuid', foreignField: '_id', as: 'person' } },
{ $unwind: { path: '$person', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },




       {
     $project: {
                _id:{
                    
                   "visit":"$id",
                    "visitdate":"$visitdate"
                    "genderuid": "$person.genderuid"
                    }

  }
},


{ $lookup: { from: 'referencevalues', localField: '_id.genderuid', foreignField: '_id', as: 'gender' } },
{ $unwind: { path: '$gender', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

    {
 $group: {

                
            "visit_date": "$_id.visitdate"
            "gender": "$gender.valuedescription",
                
}
  }



],
"cursor":{
batchSize: 100000
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sum with condition.

```
Male: {$sum: {
        $cond: [
            { $eq: [ '$gender.value', 1 ] }
            1,
            0
        ]
    }
},
Female: {$sum: {
        $cond: [
            { $eq: ['$gender.value', 0 ] }
            1,
            0
        ]
    }
}
```